# $_POST is empty even with correct reference

Tags: php, post

Obviously I say it has a correct 'name' attribute reference but something clearly isn't working.

HTML:

```
<form action="scripts/upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select Content to Upload:
        <br>
        <input type="file" name="filesToUpload[]" multiple="multiple" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Content">
    </form>
```

PHP:

```
var_dump($_POST); print "<br>"; var_dump($_FILES); print "<br>";print "<br>";
if (isset($_POST['filesToUpload'])) {
    print $_POST['filesToUpload'];
}   else {print "POST not set";}
```

OUTPUT:

```
array(0) { }
array(1) { ["filesToUpload"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "Chimera.jpeg" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "/tmp/phptdEVQ9" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(28671) } } }
array(0) { }
POST not set
```

So $_FILES got initialized, but why not $_POST?  Why is it telling me the $_POST array is not set.  I know it isn't based on the output, but shouldn't it be?  I feel like I'm making some stupid syntax error.

Comment: You have no post inputs so post would be empty. What are you thinking should be in the `$_POST`? Add  `<input type="text" name="postkey" value="whatever" />` then $_POST should populate.

Comment: When you have an input type as `file`, it pushes to the `$_FILES` array rather than `$_POST` array.

Comment: I am testing a feature.  I thought if the data was sent to `$_POST` then I can try to circumvent the upload somehow.  I want to perform some actions on the data in the `$_FILES` array without using `$_FILES` because then it otherwise implies that the file has been temporarily uploaded.  I want to perform actions before it even uploads, such as check existing equivalent names and other data validation.  Performing data validation on `_$FILES` array data is not true data validation as the files are then already uploaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking in the wrong super global. You've uploaded a `file`, so it'll be accessible in the `$_FILES` super global, that you've already `var_dump($_FILES)`'ed.

Any other `input`'s will be added to your `$_POST`. You'll be able to access the files via the `$_FILES` array:

```
foreach($_FILES['filesToUpload'] as $uploaded_file){
    print_r($uploaded_file);
    // do what you need to do with the files.
}
```

Comment: Clears it up.  Thanks,  So `$_POST` will only capture the data in the `value` attribute.  See post above, ideally I want to capture data near to what is in `$_FILES` before it is uploaded.

Comment: @polyphemus11 Essentially right, but it's all about the `type` attribute. The `file` will specify an actual file, hence it goes to the `$_FILES` array, while anything else `text/password/email/submit/etc` all go to the `$_POST` (*or `$_GET` depending on form method*),

Answer (score 2):

All files are present within the `$_FILES` super global, not `$_POST`.

Do a var_dump of `$_FILES` in order to see what was uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
<?php
require_once 'functions.php';


if(isset($_FILES['filesToUpload']['tmp_name'], $_POST)) {
    $files = reformat($_FILES['filesToUpload']);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $temp = $file['tmp_name'];
        $path = 'upload/'.$file['name'];//replace
        if(move_uploaded_file($temp, $path)){
            echo 'success upload';
        }else{
            echo 'failed to upload';
        }
    }
}else{
    echo 'file not uploaded';
}

?>
```

When uploading multiple files you will need to loop through the files:

```
<?php

function reformat(&$file_post) {

    $file_ary = array();
    $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
    $file_keys = array_keys($file_post);

    for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
        foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
            $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
        }
    }

    return $file_ary;
}

?>
```

`reformat()` is meant to reorganize the data structure